# SwiftUI return value from modal view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, modal-view

I currently have a `List` that is inside a modal (`.sheet`) view, and I'm trying to retrieve the tapped value from it back to the previous view. How can I achieve this?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingModal: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.showingModal.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Tap me!")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingModal, onDismiss: {
                print("Dismissed")
            }) {
                ModalView(isShowing: self.$showingModal)
            }
            Text("Selected Item: ")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ModalView: View {
    @State private var names = ["Foo", "Bar"]
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        List(names, id: \.self) { name in
            HStack {
                Text("\(name)")
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                print(name)
                self.isShowing = false
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var value = true
    
    static var previews: some View {
        ModalView(isShowing: self.$value)
    }
}
```

I'd like to set the text on the `Text` with `"Selected item"` in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't! Your .sheet view should update your model then this changes got reflected in your previous view if needed.

Here is a good resource explaining this communication:
https://youtu.be/4GjXq2Sr55Q

Comment: Thank you Allan, I was able to implement this myself before seeing the update with the video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .onChange on your binding variable. Whenever your modelview will change .onChange will be call.
like this,

```
@State var showingModal: Bool = false 
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingModal.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Tap me!")
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showingModal, onDismiss: {
            print("Dismissed")
        }) {
            ModalView(isShowing: self.$showingModal)
        }
        Text("Selected Item: ")
    }.onChange(of: showingModal) { newValue in
        //newValue is your changed value of showingModal true or false
    }
}
```